# Sort column from another sheet alphabetically

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet that has a column of names. I want to have another sheet that copies all of the entries from this column in sheet 1 and alphabetizes them automatically as I add new entries into sheet 1. How can I do this?

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. I used

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SORT(Sheet1!A2:A))
```

Comment: @Rubén `sort(A2:A)` works fine, even if the documentation suggests otherwise.